# How do I add buttons to the Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse

I'm on about my sixth version of Eclipse now, but I've never been able to work out how to add a button to the toolbar.
For example, by default I have a little "open type" button in the Java perspective, and I would like to add an "open type hierarchy" button right next to it. Both functions are available right next to each other on the Navigate menu, and I would simply like to drag one of them onto a toolbar as well.

Doesn't seem so far fetched to me? I've tried the "customize perspective" by right-clicking the toolbars, but to no avail. I seem to be able to add stuff that I don't want. Any ideas? I happen to be using `Eclipse 3.4.2 M20081224-0800`, but I've never gotten anywhere with this in multiple versions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick with "Customize perspective" is that only reflects 'plugin.xml' [**org.eclipse.ui.commands**](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_commands.htm) contribution points.

In other word, you can activate/deactivate those extension points, not change them.

As described in [this message](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg07380.html) (for another button):

> As far as I know, the so-called 'basic' toolbar cannot be configured by the user.
>
> I think there are 2 ways to add the 'save all' button:
>
> - write a plug-in that adds a new toolbar section containing the 'save all' button
> - patch the plug-in '`org.eclipse.ui.ide`':
>     in the class `WorkbenchActionBuilder` insert the following line after
>     the line # 374 (if you want it to appear between 'save' and 'print'):

```
fileToolBar.add(saveAllAction);
```

Eclipse3.5 [might have changed that, though.](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg23990.html)

Comment: Ah, looks like I'll be upgrading to 3.5 in June then! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a button called external tools button in the new eclipse Helios toolbar It is easy to customize. I use it for run ant build by single click
I guess it will useful try it

Answer (score 0):

There must be a way as the old GWT plugin had both the "new web application" and the "compile" buttons on the toolbar.

The latest version they are off by default.