# Add shortcut button to comment out code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, shortcut

Just wondering if there is a way to add a button to the eclipse editor - like in Visual Studio - in the "Java view" to quickly comment or uncomment out selected blocks of code?

Answer (score 5):

Using the keyboard shortcut isn't easier? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Comment: Apparently customizing the toolbar is not so easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681113/how-do-i-add-buttons-to-the-eclipse-toolbar

Comment: Not a fan of answering a question with another question. Also, I know this is old, but, is there a way now? Boy I like Visual Studio.