# Add button to comment out code in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, comments

I want a button (or two) to comment/uncomment Python code in Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Oxygen.
I searched through the site and found this question which is exactly the same as mine but several years old:

[Add shortcut button to comment out code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878434/add-shortcut-button-to-comment-out-code-in-eclipse)

I thought about asking again since we are in 2018 and I still have not found an answer different to using key combinations which I tend to forget. I also don´t know if that would work for other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try that, it should work: `CTRL + /`

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I wanted a solution different to key combinations.

Comment: Well what solution do you want?

Comment: I always forget the key combinations. I was hoping that one could add and configure a button (switch comments) or two buttons (comment / comment out). I read that 4 years ago someone managed to add buttons for redo/undo with a file plugin.xml inside the dropins directory, a jar, etc. I did not succeed to do it but I thought what I wanted could be possible.

Comment: Well using `CTRL + /` is the standard way. If you use it enough you'll get used to it, trust me :)

Comment: OK. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: If it helped remember to mark as correct answer @nanunga