# How can I add the most common mercurial commands to an Eclipse toolbar?

Tags: eclipse, version-control, mercurial, eclipse-plugin, toolbar

I'm sick of doing *Right Click -> Team -> Commit* etc. every time I want to access a Mercurial command, and I'm not inclined to learning new keyboard shortcuts.

> **Is there an easy way to add the most important Mercurial commands**
>   (push, pull, commit, update, merge, ...) to an **Eclipse toolbar**
>    *without* [writing my own plugin to do the job](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html)?

It's possible for git (*right click on toolbar -> customize perspective -> git*), so I'm having a hard time believing that nobody came up with a plugin to accomplish the same for Mercurial.

All I found after an extensive search was this [unassigned proposal](https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/231/provide-eclipse-toolbar-with-most-used) in the issue tracker of the MercurialEclipse plugin bitbucket repository. It has had the status `new` even though it was proposed nearly three years ago, so I don't suppose the developer is going to implement it in the near future...

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did I do anything wrong with this question, or is there simply no answer? Any suggestions for edits would be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't believe that it has been missing there for such a long time, it shouldn't be that difficult to add it. For me I had to use shortcut keys like the ones for git in Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to add custom toolbars to Eclipse without writing a plug in to do it.  Other people have asked similar questions: [How do I add buttons to the Eclipse toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681113/how-do-i-add-buttons-to-the-eclipse-toolbar)

The top answer for [How to add undo / redo buttons to toolbar in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819846/how-to-add-undo-redo-buttons-to-toolbar-in-eclipse) does seem to indicate that it's not too hard to write a plugin for Eclipse.  You'd have the task of finding out correct command ids to be able to do this.

Alternatively, you could show the Team Synchronize view which would then need you to right click on the Uncommitted node and select Commit.  Not many fewer clicks but less mouse travelling.

Comment: upvoted, considering to mark as answer unless someone can point me to a plugin someone else has written to accomplish this....